# Could this work (send mass newsletter email w/ ASP.NET (C#))

Tags: c#, email, newsletter

I am working on a site and it has to have a newsletter sending functionality. A couple of weeks ago I posted a question on stackoverflow, and the good people suggested that I do a console app which I call from the site and it sends the mails. I did this, and it works locally, but I wasn't able to get it working on the server (security issue). Been trying to make this work for the past 3 days. So then, I decidet to try and change how the email is sent.
To make a long story short, now I split all the emails in "groups" of 50, and then make a new `MailMessage` object, and `mailMessage.To.add(sample@sample.com)` emails to it. Then I send it 50 by 50.

It works for now, but my question is, how "BAD" is this solution? I tryed adding the emails to bcc, but for some reason (for me) this works only locally ( !?! ).

And one more thing which I couldn't find on line, what is the maximum number of mails I can add to the `MailMessage` object?

Thank you for your time!

Andrej

Comment: whats the connection of splitting the job with regards to security issue?

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't understand the question.. can you clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its **very bad** since each user which receives your newsletter will have access to the 49 other contacts (*where do i sign up?*)

If you are having problems with multiple BCC's, contact you SMTP host.

Did you try sending each separately? if it is taking to long to send, you can build a multi-threaded solution which will help.

Comment: the BCC issue is very strange to me, becouse when I send it throung my mail.domain.com offline it works, and the SAME settings don't work when I upload the files online...

Comment: and yea... forgot about everybody beeing able to see each others emails... :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to send each one his mail and you create a queue in memory on in database for store mail before send.
Remember send all emails in 1 time if you use public smtp server is bad thing, you can be banned for that server,this means you must schedule such as 1000 mail at time or less.

i have wrote this years ago if you need i can post same code

Comment: I would be very thankfull since i'm still currently trying to make this work... i have the emails stored in a db i just need the logic to make it work...